# Is it possible to auto-import file into every server endpoint for Nuxt3

Tags: nuxtjs3

I'm really liking Nuxts new server/api folder, but i've been trying to figure out if there is anyway to import a module that is available for use in every endpoint (so I don't have to import it everytime).

This is particularly useful for modules that are used in almost every endpoint (like `moment` for example)

For example in a file like this

`/server/api/create-event.js`

```js
import moment from 'moment'
export default defineEventHandler(async event => {
    console.log(moment().format(), 'creating event at this time');
})
```

I would want to simplify it down to:

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async event => {
  console.log(moment().format(), 'creating event at this time');
})
```

So there is no need for an import moment in every single endpoint.

I tried setting up the server middleware but that seems to apply more to the routes then the server function.  I'm not sure if it's even possible at the moment but would be very useful.

Comment: There is probably a way to install it globally for the whole project. Not sure how but one thing is sure: don't use moment anymore.

Comment: @kissu Yeah just as an example, would love to find if there is a way to do this in Nuxt3

Comment: I mean, installing it as a plugin is one way of doing so. Then, I'm not sure how you can get the Nuxt content into the routes but should be feasible I guess.